Extracting SQL JOIN condition column names not working with Antlr using Python
The code below is my attempt to identify join relationships between tables in a Oracle database.
The idea is to build a map of joins to help identify implicit FK relationships.
In the code below I use the PlSqlParserListener to walk the parse tree.
In the Join_on_partContext handler I breakout all the child tokens and try to get check if these are column names (I also want table names but keeping this example simple ).
The end result I would like is a list or similar which shows:
                  <---   Joins To   --->
Table  Column     Table   Column
----------------------------------------
t1     id1        t2      id1
t2     col5       t3a     t3a_col3
t2     col5       t3      col3        <--- Ideally resolve inline view aliases to actual tables and columns

The script would be run against an entire codebase to build a list of all table JOIN relationships.
On the surface this sounds like simply a case of getting each JOIN ON condition, and splitting out the left and right side of the expression. But you can get things like:
FROM tabB tB JOIN tabA tA ON tA.colA  = NVL( tB.col1, tB.col2 )
Which I would want to show as
                  <---   Joins To   --->
Table  Column     Table   Column
----------------------------------------
tabB   col1       tabA    colA
tabB   col2       tabA    colA

The code below is a first attempt to extract out the table and columns names as separate values. My plan  is to add a cross check against a list of table/column names to verify whether we have a real table/column or an alias/expression that we need to parse further.
import antlr4
from PlSqlLexer import PlSqlLexer
from PlSqlParser import PlSqlParser
from pretty_print_antlr_tree import to_string_tree
from PlSqlParserListener import PlSqlParserListener

class SQLListener(PlSqlParserListener):

    def is_column_name(self, token, ctx):
        for child_ctx in ctx.getChildren():
            if isinstance(child_ctx, PlSqlParser.Column_nameContext):
                token_start = child_ctx.start.tokenIndex
                token_stop = child_ctx.stop.tokenIndex
                if token.tokenIndex >= token_start and token.tokenIndex <= token_stop:
                    return True

        return False

    def enterJoin_on_part(self, ctx:PlSqlParser.Join_on_partContext):
        print('Found a join on :', ctx.getText())
        idx1 = ctx.start.tokenIndex
        idx2 = ctx.stop.tokenIndex
        istrm = ctx.parser._input
        tks = istrm.getTokens(idx1, idx2 + 1)
        for tk in tks:
            print( "      Check " , tk.text, " is a column" )
            if self.is_column_name(tk, ctx):
                print ("            join col name:" , tk.text )

    def enterTableview_name(self, ctx:PlSqlParser.Tableview_nameContext):
        print ( "   Found table name: ", ctx.getText() )

    def enterColumn_name(self, ctx:PlSqlParser.Column_nameContext):
        print('   Found a columnName:', ctx.getText() )

    def enterTable_alias(self, ctx:PlSqlParser.Table_aliasContext):
        print('   Found a table alias:', ctx.getText() )

    def enterColumn_alias(self, ctx:PlSqlParser.Column_aliasContext):
        print('   Found a column alias:', ctx.getText() )

    def enterGeneral_element(self, ctx:PlSqlParser.General_elementContext):
        print ( "   Found expression: ", ctx.getText())



sqltext = """

select t1.col1, t2,col2
from t1
join t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1
join ( select t3.col3 as t3_col3
       from t3
       where t3.col4 = 25 ) t3a on t2.col5 = t3a.t3_col3
where t1.col5 = 2024
order by 1

"""

lexer = PlSqlLexer(antlr4.InputStream(sqltext))
parser = PlSqlParser(antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer))
root = parser.sql_script()
print(to_string_tree(root, lexer.symbolicNames))
antlr4.ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(SQLListener(), root)


I am expecting the output to be:
   Found expression:  t1.col1
   Found expression:  t1
   Found expression:  t2
   Found expression:  col2
   Found table name:  t1
   Found table name:  t2
Found a join on : ont1.id1=t2.id1
   Found expression:  t1.id1
            join col name: id1       <<< Missing from actual output
   Found expression:  t1
   Found expression:  t2.id1
            join col name: id1       <<< Missing from actual output
   Found expression:  t2
   Found expression:  t3.col3
            join col name: col3       <<< Missing from actual output
   Found expression:  t3
   Found a column alias: ast3_col3
   Found table name:  t3
   Found expression:  t3.col4
            join col name: col4       <<< Missing from actual output
   Found expression:  t3
   Found a table alias: t3a
Found a join on : ont2.col5=t3a.t3_col3
   Found expression:  t2.col5
   Found expression:  t2
   Found expression:  t3a.t3_col3
            join col name: t3_col3   <<< Missing from actual output
   Found expression:  t3a
   Found expression:  t1.col5
            join col name: col5      <<< Missing from actual output
   Found expression:  t1



I am thinking maybe it would be better to fashion a state machine so I can tell when I am in a JOIN clause, then break up the "table.column", "alias.column" or "columns" token and check off against a lookup list of tables and columns. But this seems to suggest a gaping hole in the Antlr way of doing things, and makes me think there must a way to achieve what I want within the Antlr framework.
The tree output is (snipped to avoid 30,000 limit):
.
.
   ║                    ╠═ from_clause
   ║                    ║  ╠═ "from" (FROM)
   ║                    ║  ╚═ table_ref_list
   ║                    ║     ╚═ table_ref
   ║                    ║        ╠═ table_ref_aux
   ║                    ║        ║  ╚═ table_ref_aux_internal_one
   ║                    ║        ║     ╚═ dml_table_expression_clause
   ║                    ║        ║        ╚═ tableview_name
   ║                    ║        ║           ╚═ identifier
   ║                    ║        ║              ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                 ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║        ║                    ╚═ "t1" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║        ╠═ join_clause
   ║                    ║        ║  ╠═ "join" (JOIN)
   ║                    ║        ║  ╠═ table_ref_aux
   ║                    ║        ║  ║  ╚═ table_ref_aux_internal_one
   ║                    ║        ║  ║     ╚═ dml_table_expression_clause
   ║                    ║        ║  ║        ╚═ tableview_name
   ║                    ║        ║  ║           ╚═ identifier
   ║                    ║        ║  ║              ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║        ║  ║                 ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║        ║  ║                    ╚═ "t2" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║        ║  ╚═ join_on_part
   ║                    ║        ║     ╠═ "on" (ON)
   ║                    ║        ║     ╚═ condition
   ║                    ║        ║        ╚═ expression
   ║                    ║        ║           ╚═ logical_expression
   ║                    ║        ║              ╚═ unary_logical_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                 ╚═ multiset_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                    ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                       ╠═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║  ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║     ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║        ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║           ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║              ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                 ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                    ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                    ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                    ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                    ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                    ║           ╚═ "t1" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                    ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                    ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                       ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                          ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║                             ╚═ "id1" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║        ║                       ╠═ relational_operator
   ║                    ║        ║                       ║  ╚═ "=" (EQUALS_OP)
   ║                    ║        ║                       ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                          ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                             ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║        ║                                ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                                   ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                                      ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║        ║                                         ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║        ║                                            ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║        ║                                            ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║        ║                                            ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                                            ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║        ║                                            ║           ╚═ "t2" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║        ║                                            ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║        ║                                            ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║        ║                                               ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║        ║                                                  ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║        ║                                                     ╚═ "id1" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║        ╚═ join_clause
   ║                    ║           ╠═ "join" (JOIN)
   ║                    ║           ╠═ table_ref_aux
   ║                    ║           ║  ╠═ table_ref_aux_internal_one
   ║                    ║           ║  ║  ╚═ dml_table_expression_clause
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ╠═ "(" (LEFT_PAREN)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ╠═ select_statement
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║  ╚═ select_only_statement
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║     ╚═ subquery
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║        ╚═ subquery_basic_elements
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║           ╚═ query_block
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ╠═ "select" (SELECT)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ╠═ selected_list
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║  ╚═ select_list_elements
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║     ╚═ expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║        ╚═ logical_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║           ╚═ unary_logical_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║              ╚═ multiset_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                 ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                    ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                       ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                          ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                             ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                   ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                      ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                      ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                      ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                      ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                      ║           ╚═ "t3" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                      ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                      ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                         ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                            ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                                               ╚═ "col3" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ╠═ from_clause
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║  ╠═ "from" (FROM)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║  ╚═ table_ref_list
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║     ╚═ table_ref
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║        ╚═ table_ref_aux
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║           ╚═ table_ref_aux_internal_one
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║              ╚═ dml_table_expression_clause
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                 ╚═ tableview_name
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                    ╚═ identifier
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                       ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                          ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ║                             ╚═ "t3" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║              ╚═ where_clause
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                 ╠═ "where" (WHERE)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                 ╚═ condition
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                    ╚═ expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                       ╚═ logical_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                          ╚═ unary_logical_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                             ╚═ multiset_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ╠═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║  ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║     ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║        ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║           ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║              ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                 ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                    ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                    ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                    ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                    ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                    ║           ╚═ "t3" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                    ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                    ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                       ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                          ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║                             ╚═ "col4" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ╠═ relational_operator
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ║  ╚═ "=" (EQUALS_OP)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                   ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                      ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                         ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                            ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                               ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                                  ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                                     ╚═ constant
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                                        ╚═ numeric
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ║                                                           ╚═ "25" (UNSIGNED_INTEGER)
   ║                    ║           ║  ║     ╚═ ")" (RIGHT_PAREN)
   ║                    ║           ║  ╚═ table_alias
   ║                    ║           ║     ╚═ identifier
   ║                    ║           ║        ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║           ║           ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║           ║              ╚═ "t3a" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║           ╚═ join_on_part
   ║                    ║              ╠═ "on" (ON)
   ║                    ║              ╚═ condition
   ║                    ║                 ╚═ expression
   ║                    ║                    ╚═ logical_expression
   ║                    ║                       ╚═ unary_logical_expression
   ║                    ║                          ╚═ multiset_expression
   ║                    ║                             ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║                                ╠═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║  ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║     ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║                                ║        ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║           ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║              ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║                                ║                 ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ║           ╚═ "t2" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║                                ║                    ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                ║                       ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                ║                          ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                ║                             ╚═ "col5" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║                                ╠═ relational_operator
   ║                    ║                                ║  ╚═ "=" (EQUALS_OP)
   ║                    ║                                ╚═ relational_expression
   ║                    ║                                   ╚═ compound_expression
   ║                    ║                                      ╚═ concatenation
   ║                    ║                                         ╚═ model_expression
   ║                    ║                                            ╚═ unary_expression
   ║                    ║                                               ╚═ atom
   ║                    ║                                                  ╚═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                                     ╠═ general_element
   ║                    ║                                                     ║  ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                                     ║     ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                                     ║        ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                                     ║           ╚═ "t3a" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ║                                                     ╠═ "." (PERIOD)
   ║                    ║                                                     ╚═ general_element_part
   ║                    ║                                                        ╚═ id_expression
   ║                    ║                                                           ╚═ regular_id
   ║                    ║                                                              ╚═ "col2" (REGULAR_ID)
   ║                    ╠═ where_clause
   ║                    ║  ╠═ "where" (WHERE)
   ║                    ║  ╚═ condition
   ║                    ║     ╚═ expression
.
.
.

   ╚═ "<EOF>"




Could you add a print(to_string_tree(root, lexer.symbolicNames)) after the root = parser... like and include the tree output in the question?

Updated with tree print. Had to snip this as full tree caused the body to go over the 30,000 limit. The JOIN nodes are p[resent in full.

Could you edit your question and clearly indicate what exactly you're trying to extract from the example?

@BartKiers I've amended the question with some more details and intended purpose and output.

You need to perform attribute analysis that equates sets of columns. You will need inherited attributes to associate tabB with tB because tB is used in the join expression. And, you will need to have synthesized attributes to accumulate a set of column references used in the join expression. In the expression tA.colA  = NVL( tB.col1, tB.col2 ), the two synthesized (one for each LHS and RHS of a rel op expr) are sets { tA.colA ] and { tB.col1 tB.col2 }. You can then output the complete table at an relational_expression node with a relational_operator/EQUALS_OP.

You will also need to include any WHERE clause expressions that are themselves join conditions.
